# What is the term for a class with no functionality, it just stores data?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

What is the term/pattern for a class which has no functionality of its own, it just has public data?

I use this pattern all the time as step one of extracting a class.  I create a class which only has data attributes.  I then refactor the target functions to use an instance of it instead of whatever storage it was using, usually a hash.  Then the function can be moved to the new class with much less change.

[Here is an example of this in Perl](https://github.com/schwern/method-signatures/commit/40b89088ec7b182b708e6e592a92eacd323cc772).

Comment: We've always called these PODS or “[Plain Old Data Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value Object is another term I've used / seen used.

Comment: I'm not sure how universal that might be, as in there.net world value types are a special kind of class.

Comment: @andy - In PureMVC a value object is defined exactly as you define it in your answer above: http://mariusht.com/blog/2009/05/21/puremvc-in-a-week/ (you'll have to scroll down a wee bit). Maybe it's fairly specific to PureMVC but I think it's a reasonable way of describing such an object. Plus it's more succinct, if you're, like, into the whole brevity thing.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your answer, I just dont think its as common.  Value types in .net refer to something specific, and DDD has a definition for value objects as well, and again its different than anything else mentioned here.

Comment: Value object!  Yes, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @andy - No worries, I knew you weren't disagreeing. I just thought I'd explain where my understanding of the term came from. Hope I didn't come across as argumentative because that really wasn't my intention.

Answer (score 2):

I usually call these data transfer objects, DTOs, as their responsibility is usually  carrying data from one tier to another.